# How to create multiple threaded Forms as MDIChild

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to have multiple threaded forms as MDIChild? I have an ActiveX control in MdiChild form that can take a lot of processing CPU, and would like to make that one control will not influence another control by using sample code below. But line frmDoc.MdiParent = Me throws cross threading exception.

```
Dim frmDoc As MDIChild
Dim newThread As New Thread(
    Sub()
        frmDoc = New MDIChild
        frmDoc.MdiParent = Me '<- this line throws cross threading exception.
        Application.Run(frmDoc)
    End Sub
)
newThread.IsBackground = True
newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
newThread.Start()
```

Throws System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled:

```
Message=Cross-thread operation not valid: 
  Control 'FormMdiApp' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
Source=System.Windows.Forms
```

Comment: Can you make this form with the ActiveX control a non-MDI form?

Comment: Just thinking, is that possible to be done in C++ MFC app?

Comment: I don't know about C++ MFC, but if you simply change `frmDoc` to a non-MDI child form, it should work. You will have to be careful to `Invoke` any time you need to access it from another thread, of course.

Comment: I think my only option is to follow "MTMDI Sample: Demonstrates an MFC User Interface Thread" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3wsyb55%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Show more details on the "threading exception".

Answer (score 3):

GUI elements must be initialized and accessed in the main event loop only. You can process heavy calculations asynchronously or in background threads.

Comment: It is possible to have multiple forms each with their own thread and message loop, but I don't think it will work with MDI children.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, is this reasonable to do so? I've never faced multiple forms in multiple threads. Can you show examples? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's feasible. Basically you do what OP is doing, except not with MDI forms. In a new (STA) thread, you create a form, then pass it to Application.Run, which sets up a new event-loop for you. You need to be careful to Invoke any cross-thread calls, but it works.

Comment: For example Google Chrome runs each tab in a separate process

Comment: @walter: Google Chrome also doesn't run on WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

try BackgroundWorker http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.95).aspx

Perform all the heavy opration in DoWork event and use the ProgressChanged/RunWorkerCompleted event to update the UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Available options on how to implement this

- Switch to VC++ MFC framework and follow [MTMDI Sample: Demonstrates an MFC User Interface Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3wsyb55%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- As it was suggested by [@Blorgbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369/blorgbeard) replace MdiChild with Forms
- Look at [Running a WPF control in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029109/running-a-wpf-control-in-another-thread)

Just found a good msdn support article [How To Create Windows in a Multithreaded Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/90975/en-us)

> Creating a window can force an implicit [AttachThreadInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(), when a
>   parent window is created in one thread and the child window is being
>   created in another thread. When windows are created (or set) in
>   separate threads with a parent-child relationship, the input queues
>   are attached.

More information can be found on 
[Walkthrough: Supporting COM Interop by Displaying Each Windows Form on Its Own Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233639%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Similar question was asked [Spawn a new thread to open a new window and close it from a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698080/spawn-a-new-thread-to-open-a-new-window-and-close-it-from-a-different-thread)

But, anfortunatelly non of those have anything about child forms.

Update: Just have found bugs in Walkthrough code; but overall this sample has some good ideas.